# Are there any standards for defining your own ARINC 429 labels?

Tags: arinc-429

Is anyone aware of any ground rules or best practices for defining your own ARINC 429 labels? Are there certain ranges of labels that correspond to groups of parameters like engine temps, rpms, etc?  Am I basically free to start at Label 000 and define my own words?

Comment: What is your need for new labels? Do you have an existing ARINC compatible product that you just want to add some labels to an existing bus? Define a new output bus with new data? The point of ARINC is interoperability. Unless you are building both ends of the bus, you should be working with the relevant AEEC committee. If it’s a standalone project that won’t ever connect to an external product, you can do pretty much what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Appendix E of the ARINC 429 Part 1 spec dated 2004 provides the guidelines for label assignments such as:

- label ranges for BNR/BCD/Discrete data
- Maintenance vs normal data

Label 000 should not be used and label 377 is reserved for the Equipment Identification.

What ultimately matters, however, is that the receiving equipment knows how to decode the labels it receives.

Comment: I have a copy of the ARINC 429 Part 1 spec dated 2019, and it does not have an Appendix E. Is this in a different Part of the specification?

Comment: I don't have access to the 2019 version, but in the 2004 version it is in ARINC 429 Part 1